# JQuery autoloading user functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, onload

I am quite new to JQuery, and I am learning every day. But now I am quita stuck...
For something that should be fairly simple I cannot get to work.

I have a function that I want to run on loading. But the  system does not allow me.
I have written the following code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TestFunction(){
            alert('We are just testing!');
        }
        function TestFunctionTwo(){
            alert('Yes really!');
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            TestFunction();
            TestFunctionTwo();
        }
    </script>
```

As you see the two alerts should be given.
But unfortunately the system does nothing.

I hope that someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have seen several similair questions. However none of their solutions "seem" to work for me. Maybe there is one critical comma that I am adding or forgetting. But I do not seem to get it :-(

Comment: I hope the src u have written to include the jquery library is fine?

Comment: Missing `)` after `}`

Comment: you mean to say ..get your alerts once your page has loaded ?

Comment: Close the DOM ready function, and close the question, it's just a typo.

Comment: ...or just check your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brackets repairs were not complete.

```
 <script src="------Your jQuery location -------------"></script>
    <script>
        function TestFunction(){
            alert('We are just testing!');
        }
        function TestFunctionTwo(){
            alert('Yes really!');
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            TestFunction();
            TestFunctionTwo();
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close the ready function properly.should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      TestFunction();
      TestFunctionTwo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply made a syntactic error. The ready-function is not closed.

To prevent this in the feature, learn to use your browsers console.